# file transfer in packet in C#

Tags: c#, file, stream, packet, transfer

I am trying to transfer a sample video file (approx 20 MB)  from one PC to another in chunks. I can transfer image fine but not a video. I convert files to bytes and transfer and dump them in file using filestream. but the file plays just 1-3 frames. I have tried different ways (with limited knowledge I have or what I can find on the internet). I read somewhere about packetized transfer, but not sure what to do or where to start. Can anyone please point me to some link or point me to the right direction?

Comment: Do you really need to mess with the bytes? Why not just use [`System.IO.File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx)

Comment: Post your code. We can't see what's wrong without seeing the code. Also - are you making sure to `Flush` your stream?

Comment: @Conrad thanks for the tips. I will definitly try that. Also eventually I may have to move larger files.

Comment: @Dave yes I am flushing streams after a complete transfer. I can also see my stream lenght is somewhat close what I have transferred. So I am assuming when I am dumping they are not in right order (read something like this), and sending in packets is the way to keep these chunks in order. but not sure how to go about creating and maintain packetized file transfer process.

Comment: The only difference between large files and small ones is that you may want to 1) Show progress and 2) use cancelable IO. To do this and still use the Win32 functionality (which is what `File.Move` does) you can use `MoveFileWithProgress`. There's no Framework wrapper for it though so you'll have to use P/Invoke. Doing a web search for MoveFileWithProgess C# should be helpful

Comment: @Conrad I need to transfer file from one PC to another, not moving file from one location to another. But thanks for the tips.

Comment: @jef is there a reason you'd have trouble using a UNC path for the destFileName?

Comment: I only have access to stream so I have to transfer the files using that. So UNC is not applicable in this case. Thanks.